# How can we prove that an affine function can be written as $f(x)=ax+b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Sorry if duplicate. Searched but could not find anything.
I understand the concept of an affine function. I am not sure as to how to go about writing a proof for the definition $f(x)=ax+b$ where $\vec{a}$ is a vector and $b$ is a scalar.

Comment: How do you define *affine function* ?

Comment: Definitions are not proved.

Comment: the scalar is $a$ and the vector is $b$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Let $f \colon V \to K$ be affine. Show that $f - f(0)$ is linear.